# elm-css: What happened to mixins in elm-css 9.0?

Tags: elm

My code broke when I upgraded from elm-css 8.x to 9.0. It looks like mixins are no longer in the documentation. What happened to them, or what were mixins replaced with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `Mixin`s were replaced with `Style`s. You can compose `Style`s to make other `Style`s (which essentially is what mixins are for in preprocessors like Sass or Less)

This Elm code ...

```
greenOnHover : Mixin
greenOnHover =
   mixin
        [ hover [ color (rgb 0 0 122) ]
        ]
```

should be replaced with

```
greenOnHover : Style
greenOnHover =
    batch
        [ hover [ color (rgb 0 0 122) ]
        ]
```

[There is some information in this pull request](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-css/pull/253)